# BlackBerry horizontal context menu

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to create a horizontally arranged context menu.   This means when my application is running and I press the menu button that my customized horizontal options will show. How do I do this on BlackBerry?

Comment: What is your target OS and SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You can override `onMenu` method in the `Screen` class and show your custom `PopupScreen` menu.

Answer (score -1):

This can be accomplished as @Eugen Martynov has mentioned. Though your idea might sound novel, it doesn't go with the UI guidelines of a Blackberry application. Regular Blackberry users might not appreciate the new UI you are proposing. And moreover, there is a possibility of your app being rejected when you submit for certification to host in Blackberry App World.

Check the guide lines [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-App-World-Development/Process-flow-for-submitted-applications-and-releases/ta-p/445767)

Point no 3.4 mentions that the user must be able to use "Switch Application" feature from within the application. Though you might design the app to adhere, there is a possibility of rejection for non-standard implementation.